# 'revert' bash to searching correct history file

Tags: bash, history

I recently decided it would be a good idea to start backing up my history, and did so with the following added to `.bashrc`:

```
 export HISTFILE=~/.history/`date +%Y%m%d`.hist
 export HISTSIZE=100000
```

No problem, seems to do what it says it should do.

However I noticed today (after my first log back in to the shell since setting it) that my actual history as recalled by `history` (or when grepping for patterns within) itself, was only showing my commands since that log in, it was as if the backup had also erased `.bash_history`.

When I inspected `.bash_history` manually with `less`, it was all there as I had expected it should be.

i.e., the output of a `tail` to `history` is:

```
wms_joe@Esau:~$ history | tail
48  past dir
49  ll
50  less .bash_history
51  tail .bash_history
52  cp .bash_history history_backup
53  past usearch
54  less ~/.bashrc
55  history
56  tail history
57  history | tail
```

But a `tail` to .bash_history gives:

```
wms_joe@Esau:~$ tail .bash_history
cd prot_all/
ls
find . -type f -name *.txt -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /XBW1/d
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /XBW1/d
less PAU_03392_out.txt
less ../../PVC_operons/prot_all/PAU_03392_out.txt
past cut
less PAU_03392_out.txt
cut -f3 PAU_03392_out.txt | bc
less PAU_03392_out.txt
```

And these are files etc. I know I was working on recently, and their command IDs should be up in to the 4000-5000 region, not 50 or so.

So my question being, how to I make `history` look at the right thing again? Or can I somehow merge the contents of `.bash_history` back in to the history so that it is recalled by the command correctly?

Comment: Try setting your history file in .bashrc back to the right location

Comment: Note you can explicitly read or write a history file with `history -r filename` and `history -w filename`. See also options `-a` and `-n`.

Comment: basically you change history file to a day base history file, wait a day, re-log, and now history has changed. That waht you asked for.

Comment: I was following a guide on some other page, but I didn't realise it would be 'resetting' the history file. I though it was basically just writing a copy of it each day, not actually changing the focus of `history`.

Comment: @John has got the idea spot on. All I had to do was `export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history` and it's back to normal. I'll rethink my backup approach when I come to look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

You must set `HISTSIZE=0` to close the old `$HISTFILE` before making your changes. See `man bash`.